# Asp.net Ajax pageMethods not triggering success event handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, pagemethods

I have asp.net ajax page method like following,

```
   [WebMethod]
   public static string UnAuthVote(string vf) 
   {          
       return "";

   }
```

and I am calling it like this,

```
PageMethods.UnAuthVote("alikhan", success1, error);
```

And my success1 and error method written like following,

```
  function success1(response) {alert("");

       return false;
}
    function error(error) {alert("error");return false; }
```

The problem is it's invoking error event. Why my code is not calling pagemethod's success event.

help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was using url rewriting. So that's why my pagemethods was not working.

Well

I set set_Path property like following

```
PageMethods.set_path("Auth/profile.aspx")
```

Now it's working as it should

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you show the actual error, for example:

```
 function success1(response) 
 {
   alert(response);
 }
 function error(error) 
 {
   alert(error);
 }
```

You can also use a debugger or developer tools to identify the problem. The error may show on the Console tab. The debugger will allow you to troubleshoot more efficiently than editing code to show `alerts` but I understand that in some cases this is preferable. You can also write to the `console` by doing:

```
 function success1(response) 
 {
   if(window.console) console.log(response);
 }
 function error(error) 
 {
   if(window.console) console.log(error);
 }
```

The benefit of this is it doesn't get in the user's way, and is only visible if the console is open. Checking for window.console avoids exceptions thrown from logging to console if it is unavailable.

If you don't know the properties of the return objects you can iterate through them like this:

```
   function error(error) 
     {
         var output = [];
         for(key in error)
         {
             output[output.length] = key.toString() + " = " + error[key];
         }
         alert(output.join('\n'));
     }
```

Comment: You will need to check the properties of the error object via debugger or API. I think it is `error.description` but can't remember off top of my head. I gave some generic code to spit out all properties above.